# How to type some fields of an object in typecsript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to strongly type only a subset of an object? I tried doing this:

```
const foo = {
  // many properties here which are inferred (primitives)
  nested: {} as {} | { bar: string }
}

// simulating something that might happen
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  foo.nested.bar = 'bar'
  // Getting the following error
  // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{} | { bar: string; }'.
  // Property 'bar' does not exi st on type '{}'.

}

// Getting the same error
// Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{} | { bar: string; }'.
// Property 'bar' does not exi st on type '{}'.
console.log(foo.nested.bar)
```

Is there no way of doing it?

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: Does this help? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: Shouldn't that be an intersection type instead of a union type?  i.e. `nested: {} as {} & { bar: string }` ?  My interpretation of this question is that `bar` will always be present in the object no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The union type you are declaring `{} | {bar: string}` won't give you access to `bar`. Typescript allows manipulating a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) only when the operation is valid for all types that participate in the union. Since `{}` doesn't have a `bar` key, you can't access `bar` on variables of type `{} | {bar: string}`, just as the error tells you.

If your goal is just to initialize `nested` with an empty object, you can define `bar` as optional:

`nested: { bar?: string }`

This allows you to assign the empty object: `nested = {}`.